# How to get an object array in a Web API response in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

Along with the response code, I need to return a `regionobject`, `projectobject`, `sectionobject`, and `flightobject`. How do I return an array of different object types?

GET Region filled (URL parameter):

http://host:port/regions?type=filled

This should return an HTTP 200 response with a JSON array (`application/json`).

---

```
[
  {regionobject},
  {projectobject},
  {sectionobject},
  {…}
]
```

### `regionobject` structure:

```
{
  "region_id": value,
  "region_name": value,
  "region_fullname": value,
  "region_type": value,
  "region_misc": value,
  "projects": [{projectobject},{…}…]
}
```

### `projectobject` structure:

```
{
  "project_id": value,
  "project_name": value,
  "project_code": value,
  "project_description": value,
  "region_id": value, // (to avoid redundancy)
  "epsg": value,
  "sections": [{sectionobject},{…}…]
}
```

### `sectionobject` structure:

```
{
  "section_id": value,
  "section_name": value,
  "section_description": value,
  "flights": [{flightobject},{…}…]
}
```

Comment: do you mind editing your post, making the json structure more pretty and readable ?

Comment: @Kevin Can you please help me with this

Comment: I had a similar DTO deserialization requirement before. You can check this [git](https://gist.github.com/osisdie/09890e56ccb8a61eb558898f2aea5e4b) example and might give you an aid.

Comment: It would be useful to have, at minimum, the output you’re actually receiving. My assumption is that you’re only seeing the shared properties from the shared base type, but that would help illustrate what’s not working for you. It might also be nice to have the relevant code from your controller’s `Region` action, to show how you’re serializing your objects.